# How do I make a counter to show the level I am on in a question game?

Tags: c, counter

I need to make a math question game that asks a random question per level. So starting at level 1 it would ask a question and if answered correctly then the user can move to level 2 and so on. I am not sure how to make a counter that keeps raising the level as the questions are answered i.e. level 1, 2,3 etc. and at the end state what level the user got to? I know the basic code to start it but not sure what to do after this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()

int i;

for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
```

Comment: So you want 1001 levels?  See the `for` loop answer below, but there is much to do after that.  Where will get get your questions from? How will you check the answers?  How will your user succeed or fail at each level?  So you have many design questions to think about, and several syntax errors to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `int i;`. You can use the `i` that is already initialized in the loop. This `i` can be used inside the for loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

This will print numbers 1-10. Can you solve the problem knowing this?

Comment: I know how to print random numbers like 1-10 but I need to have it print for example "level 1" then the user answers the question and then have it read level 2 and so on after each correct answer. Then at the end when the user exits it needs to say how many levels were completed.

Comment: Make an `int x = 0`, then add 1 to it for each iteration of the loop. At the start of a level and the end of the game print the int. I recommend using a while loop for this, what if the user gets to level 1001?